# Flink AssignTimeStampsAndWaterMark

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to count the status code of health check data by request_time with a 1 minute window from the current time.

It's known that the health check sends about 60 requests per minute. So the result should be like `{environment: "XX", host: "XX", 200: 60, 300: 0, 400: 0, 500: 0}`

But the actual result is `{environment: "XX", host: "XX", 200: 50000, 300: 0, 400: 0, 500: 0}`, which counts a lot of previous data.

My code is like

```
  env.fromSource(kafkasource).filter().flatMap()
    .assignTimeStampAndWaterMarks(
    WaterMarkStrategy.<OnjectNode>forboundedOutOfOrderness(DurationOfSeconds(60).withTimeStampAssigner(assigner))
    .keyBy("env","host")
    .window(1m)
    .reduce()
```

Does anyone know what's missing or I am wrong in the logic?

Comment: Your timestamp assigner might be bugged. Are you using EventTime windows?

Comment: The problem is probably in the details. Please share enough of the actual code that we can check for misconfigurations, etc.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I added withIdleness() in the watermarkstrategy and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should provide more detail info of your code in `reduce()` and `flatmap()`. Based on currently available information， this problem may be that the state in `reduce` is not being reset. you can check the code in `reduce` or whether is correctly ttl set.

Comment: It would also be helpful to see the actual code used to create the windows.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I added withIdleness() in the watermarkstrategy and everything is fine.